# Flash SWF banner: Problem with clickTAG

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, banner, clicktag

We have created a banner that loads a game when clicked. The first screen in the banner has a link button (with url from loaderInfo.parameters.clickTAG). This click works. Once you start (load) the game (from domainB) the whole banner is clickable. When clicking the banner on the "real" site (domainA) this click does not work. However if I put main.swf on my alternative site (domainX) it works. I have tried the normal html embed and SwfObject on my alternative site. Same result. It works. We are using crossdomain (using *) on our site. The strange thing is that the first click works. The clickTag is stored in a Singleton in main.swf and used in game.swf for the later clicks.

**main.swf** *@domainA* (loading content from @domainB) // does not work

**game.swf** *@domainB*

**assets.swf** *@domainB*

---

**main.swf** *@domainX* (loading content from @domainB) // works fine

Comment: did you add traces to every step of loading? how do you load it (and did you try URLStream)? are you sure that main.swf has equal environment on domainA and domainX ?

Comment: We found the problem. The clickTAG was stored to a Singleton in main.swf (@domainA) and when we tried to access it in game.swf (@domainB) it could not be retrieved. Kind of logical. The solution was to look for stage.loaderInfo.parameters from the game.swf as well. That works. Is it possible tom make classes "communicate" on different domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the problem. The clickTAG was stored to a Singleton in main.swf (@domainA) and when we tried to access it in game.swf (@domainB) it could not be retrieved. Kind of logical. The solution was to look for stage.loaderInfo.parameters from the game.swf as well. That works. Is it possible tom make classes "communicate" on different domains?